# Is there an idiom for when the source is "clean" but the product isn't?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I was thinking of having a sentence that goes like:

> This situation presents the paradox of ________.

Basically, I want to say that it's ironic that the worst human rights abuses can be traced back to World Bank but at the same time, World Bank declares the human rights issues to be completely out of their responsibility.

What World Bank is saying is that human rights is completely outside their mandate. At the same time, they're the source of the worst human rights abuses

Comment: Does Company X actually *acknowledge* that they produce bad things—while trying to excuse it—or are they claiming that they *don't* produce bad things? (Also, your *irony* sounds like a good word in general . . .)

Comment: "it's ironic that the worst human rights abuses can be traced back to Company X but at the same time, Company X declares the human rights issues to be completely out of their responsibility" I don't see any irony here, nor do I see how you would say the source is "clean" in any way here.

Comment: I would call that *hypocrisy*.

Comment: I think you'd need to say _how_ Company X are complicit and _how_ they are able to pretend(?) to wash their hands of the human rights abuse. Please edit and add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

One would say that Company X keeps their hands clean.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiom that seems to be appropriate here:

***sail under false colors***

According to Collin's Dictionary:

To behave deceptively; 
the “colors” of a ship are its 
identifying flags:
 “It turned out
that the door-to-door sales rep
 was sailing
under false
 colors and was 
actually a swindler.”

Answer (score -1):

I would call Company X a **[wolf in sheep's clothing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wolf-in-sheeps-clothing)**.

> a malicious person in a harmless or benevolent disguise
>
> - Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers